# Reduce query time when using both MySQL and PostgreSQL with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, php, mysql

I am doing a tracking query. The device is sending its location data, timestamp to store in MySQL Database. I want to show the query result of every point with its nearest POI. The POI database is stored in PostgreSQL database as PostGIS format. Its taking 8-9 seconds to return the query result. At first I am calling the longitude latitude values from MySQL Database then calling the nearest POI info for every point from PostgreSQL database using while loop. I want to know is there any way to reduce the query time? I am using the following query

```
SELECT  name, area, district, ST_Distance(geom::geography,ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(
$longitude $latitude
)')) as distance 
FROM poi 
ORDER BY distance
Limit 1;
```

I need to get a JSON result to visualize on map.

Comment: Yes, you can use the Order by <-> approach for knn.

Comment: You should also have an index on the poi table; Make sure that it is using the `geography` since that is what you are using in your query

Answer (score 2):

The following query solve my issue

```
SELECT name, area, district, ST_Distance_Sphere(geom,'POINT($longitude $latitude)'::geometry) as distance 
FROM poi
ORDER BY
poi.geom <->'POINT($longitude $latitude)'::geometry
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This seems to work in a similar way. The <-> operator makes use of the spatial index during sorting and will speed up the query accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can't change the setup with the two databases. So let's take this as a given.

Your postgis query is very inefficient. Although you only display the first row it still computes distances to all points in the table.

Is there a max distance you want to search in?
You could add a where clause to limit the calculation to points which intersect with a certain buffer around your POI.
also make sure you have a spatial index on your point layer.

Comment: Can you give any example of use where clause or elaborate how to have a spatial index on the point layer?